# Save String column as true Json value - Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a usecase where schema of a column is String, but it's actually a json (for instance """ {"a":"b"} """). Eg:

```
scala> val list = List("a" -> """ {"a":"b","c":"d"} """, "b" -> """ {"foo" : "bar"} """)
list: List[(String, String)] = List((a," {"a":"b","c":"d"} "), (b," {"foo" : "bar"} "))

scala> val df = list.toDF("colA","colB")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [colA: string, colB: string]

scala> df.show(2,false)
+----+-------------------+
|colA|colB               |
+----+-------------------+
|a   | {"a":"b","c":"d"} |
|b   | {"foo" : "bar"}   |
+----+-------------------+
```

I need to write df as json but for colB I need to output true json and not String. For instance if I do this:

```
scala> df.repartition(1).write.json("/Users/myuser/sparkjson/3")
```

I get in json file colB as String:

```
{"colA":"a","colB":" {\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"} "}
{"colA":"b","colB":" {\"foo\":\"bar\"} "}
```

But what I want is to output true json for colB (instead of string). So something like:

```
{"colA":"a","colB": {"a":"b","c":"d"} }
{"colA":"b","colB": {"foo":"bar"} }
```

I do not have schema for colB unfortunately, it could be any valid json. How do I achieve this?

Comment: One crazy approach I was thinking was df.rdd.map(row => covert row manually to required json).saveAsTextFile(..). It's really hacky but might work. However I am writing to S3 and this approach won't let me use custom com.netflix.bdp.s3.S3DirectoryOutputCommitter. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `DataFrame` with a proper schema, in this case, the `colB` is  actually a `Map[String, String]`, an easy way to do this is create a `case class` and spark will figure out your schema automatically. Here is the code:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

case class Data(colA:String, colB:Map[String, String])

val list:List[Data] =
List("a" -> """ {"a":"b","c":"d"} """, "b" -> """ {"foo" : "bar"} """) .map {
  case (colA, colB) => 
      Data(
       colA,
       parse(colB).extract[Map[String, String]]
      )
}

val df = spark.createDataset( list )
df.write.json("/tmp/a.json")
```

Result is as below:

```
$ cat /tmp/a.json/*                                                                            
{"colA":"a","colB":{"a":"b","c":"d"}}
{"colA":"b","colB":{"foo":"bar"}}
```

Comment: I was thinking about the same, however this example for merely for illustration. Json may have ints, longs, doubles etc too. Also, this approach will not handle nested json structures.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure about this solution, but can try adding option like the following -

```
scala> df.repartition(1).write.option("escapeQuotes","false").json("/Users/myuser/sparkjson/3")
```

Comment: that option is for csv, not json